# Dplyr: group_by and operations within groups

Tags: r, dplyr

Please consider the following tibble

```
df <- structure(list(reporter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),    .Label = c("NZL", 
"SEN", "USA"), class = "factor"), partner = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("EUN", "WLD"), class = "factor"), 
number_ntm = c(389, 20874, 0, 3933, 4, 30368)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like this

```
 # A tibble: 6 x 3
reporter partner number_ntm
<fct>    <fct>        <dbl>
1 NZL      EUN            389
2 NZL      WLD          20874
3 SEN      EUN              0
4 SEN      WLD           3933
5 USA      EUN              4
6 USA      WLD          30368
```

What I would like to do is the following: group_by reporter, and within each group divide the number_ntm with partner EUN by the number_ntm with partner WLD.
I would like a dplyr solution which is fairly generic and works also when the partner structure contains some extra factors which I do not want to include.
Any suggestion appreciated

Comment: If there are only two levels `df %>% group_by(reporter) %>% mutate(new = first(number_ntm)/last(number_ntm))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as akrun suggested, but specify the partner instead of using first and last.

```
df1<-df %>%
   group_by(reporter) %>%
   mutate(new = number_ntm[partner=="EUN"]/number_ntm[partner=="WLD"])
```